# NodeJS loop wait for callback

Tags: jquery, node.js, loops

How can i wait inside a for loop until the callback was received and then continue the for loop?

Here's my loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < offer.items_to_receive.length; i++) {
    console.log("Waiting for callback...");
    doSomething(function(data) {
        console.log("Got data from callback! "  + data);
    });
    console.log("Continue for loop now.");
}
```

Thanks for inputs!

Comment: you may not be able to do that in a for loop, because `doSomething` looks to be an async method

Comment: What can be another option to do that like i want? @ArunPJohny

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h38wt723/1/ - try something like

Comment: worked fine, thanks a lot! @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to use a loop if the called method is asynchronous, instead you can use a recursion based solution like

```js
function x(items, i) {
  i = i || 0;
  if (i >= items.length) {
    return
  }
  snippet.log("Waiting for callback..." + i);
  doSomething(function(data) {
    snippet.log("Got data from callback! " + data);

    if (i == items.length - 1) {
      snippet.log("completed");
    } else {
      x(items, i + 1)
    }
  });
}

// a sample implementation of asynchronous method
var counter = 0;
function doSomething(cb) {
  setTimeout(cb.bind(window, counter++), 100)
}

x([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please do not call a function `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Generators are your friends here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

But if you are not ES6 ready yet, the concept of @Arun P Johny's post might help:

```
function getData(items) {
  if (!items.length) {
    return;
  }
  doAsyncCall(items[0], function(data) {
    getData(items.slice(1))
  });
}
```